# Joining three tables, than order, how to use index in MySql?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have these three tables:

```
season(id, season);
game_in_season(id, id_season, game);
player_in_game(id, id_game, full_name, pts);
```

I want to select all players of season with index 5 and order them by pts. Which index should I use? I have an index on pg.pts column, but it is not used when I join the table with s and gs tables. It is only used when I make "select * from pg order by pts desc".

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pg.* FROM season s, game_in_season gs, player_in_game pg
WHERE s.id = gs.id_season AND gs.id = pg.id_game
AND s.id = 5
ORDER BY pg.pts DESC
```

In a row with table = 's' there is extra = 'Using temporary; Using filesort'. Which index should I use to not using filesort? Is it even possible to make this query without using filesort?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JOIN..ON` instead of commajoin:

```
SELECT  pg.*
    FROM  season s
    JOIN  game_in_season gs  ON s.id = gs.id_season
    JOIN  player_in_game pg  ON gs.id = pg.id_game
    WHERE  s.id = 5
    ORDER BY  pg.pts DESC
```

The Optimizer has two ways to execute:

- Start by filtering `s` using `s.id = 5`, or equivalently filtering `gs` on `gs.id_season` on `gs.id_season = 5`.
- Start by using `INDEX(pts)` in `pg` (if you have such).

The former *must* sort the data after it gets to the `ORDER BY`.  The Optimizer is likely to pick this approach.

The latter is *inefficient* because it will have to read lots of unnecessary rows, since the test for `5` comes too late.

`Using temporary; Using filesort` seems to always be in the first line of `EXPLAIN`; this is confusing because

- Often the sort comes later in the processing; and
- The sort often happens in RAM, not in a "file" or with a real "temporary" table.  That is, you (and many other MySQL users) should not be scared by that 'Extra'.

I assume you have these indexes (or `PRIMARY KEYs`):

```
season:          (id)
game_in_season:  (id_season) -- Better would be (id_season, id)
player_in_game:  (id_game)
```

Bottom line:  The query is probably running as fast as it can.

*When asking performance questions, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `EXPLAIN`.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem is that it tooks too long to select player_in_games rows of one season and order them by points. It is much more faster to select all player_in_games rows and order them by points (because I have an index on pts column, but it is not used when I specify a season). Do you have any idea how to resolve it? I tried to make a view for each season but I cannot make indexes in views :(

Comment: A `VIEW` is just syntactic sugar; the underlying `SELECT` still needs to be optimized and executed.  _There is no solution for that query with that table structure._